# I can't pass a delphi string as a parameter to a cgo dll

Tags: go, delphi, dll, virtual-machine, c-strings

I have a DLL compiled in Go as a c-shared lib that takes in a string as a parameter. It works fine in other languages, like Java, and Python using `ctypes` to simulate a c-string.

But, when trying to use this DLL in Delphi, I can't pass in a string as a parameter.

This is the function declaration in Go:

```golang
//export RequestCertificate
func RequestCertificate(jsonString string) *C.char{
    log.Println("String: ", jsonString)`
```

In Python, I declared a structure that simulates a c-string like this:

```py
class GoString(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("chars", c_char_p), ("length", c_longlong)]
```

And then passed this structure as a parameter:

```py
jsonStr = json.dumps(payload)
jsonB64 = base64.b64encode(bytes(jsonStr, "ansi"))
        
goJson = GoString(jsonB64, len(jsonB64))
response = [GoString]
response = lib.RequestCertificate(goJson)
```

In the terminal, the DLL shows exactly what I expect.

```
String:  eyJ1cmwiOiAiaHR0cHM6Ly9scC5ub...
```

But, I can't replicate this in Delphi. This is how I declared the structure that simulates a c-string:

```pascal
type 
  TGoString = record
    chars: PAnsiChar;
    length: LongInt;
```

```pascal
jsonStr := payload.ToString;
jsonBytes  := TEncoding.ANSI.GetBytes(jsonStr);
jsonB64 := TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(jsonBytes);
goJson.chars := PAnsiChar(jsonB64);
goJson.length := Length(jsonB64);
response := RequestCertificate(goJson);
```

But all I get is an empty reply:

```
String:
```

I already changed the declaration of my Go function to receive a c-string instead of a Go string this way:

```golang
//export RequestCertificate
func RequestCertificate(CString *C.char) *C.char{
    log.Println("C String: ", CString)
    goString := C.GoString(CString)
    log.Println("GoString: ", goString)
```

The result in Python is this:

```
C String:  0xcbe9bef070
GoString:  eyJ1cmwiOiAiaHR0cHM6Ly9scC5ub...
```

But in Delphi, the result is this:

```
C String:  0x14feb0
GoString :
```

I also tried to encode my Delphi string in other formats instead of ANSI, but it didn't work.

What could the reason be for this behavior? Incompatibility between Delphi and Go encoding?

I am running this in a Windows virtual machine, which runs on an Ubuntu system.

Comment: Offhand, the code looks mostly fine to me. Although, the `chars` field of a Go `string` is a `byte*` pointer, so you should use `PByte` instead of `PAnsiChar` in Delphi. Also, the `length` field in a Go string is a pointer-sized integer, whereas Delphi's `LongInt` is 32bit or 64bit depending on the underlying platform, so try using `NativeInt` instead. Also, how are you declaring `RequestCertificate()` in the Delphi code, exactly? Are you passing the `TGoString` record **by value** or **by reference/pointer**? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: In particular, what *calling convention* are you using for `RequestCertificate()`? I doubt Delphi's default `register` convention is compatible with Go. See [Go internal ABI specification](https://tip.golang.org/src/cmd/compile/abi-internal). I'm not sure if Go functions are exposed to C-compatible languages (like Delphi) using `cdecl` or `stdcall` as the calling convention.

Comment: @remy python c_longlong is always 64 bit.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I didn't say anything about Python, did I? [According to this](https://go101.org/article/string.html), a string's length is an `int` which is 32bit or 64bit based on OS bitness. That would be a `NativeInt` in Delphi.

Comment: @remyLebeau the question talked about python, you did not. I guess if the code runs in a 64 bit then the python code will work but will be wrong in 32 bit according to your link. Perhaps I'm reading the wrong part of that link but len is declared int.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "*you did not [talk about python]*" - because the OP merely showed Python as an example, but is linking Delphi directly to Go, not Python. "*Perhaps I'm reading the wrong part of that link but len is declared int*" - if you read Go's actual documentation, it says: [link](https://go.dev/tour/basics/11) "*The `int`, `uint`, and `uintptr` types are usually 32 bits wide on 32-bit systems and 64 bits wide on 64-bit systems.*" And also: [link](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Numeric_types) "*`uint` - either 32 or 64 bits, `int` - same size as `uint`*"

Comment: @remy the python code in the question was presented as an example of working code. And c_longlong is 64 bits. I don't know of any compiler on Windows for which int is not always 32 bits. The original article you linked to says len is int. There is not mention of any pointer sized integers. I'm very confused.

Comment: "*The original article you linked to says len is int*" - yes, but that is a 3rd party tutorial, not official Go documentation. "*There is not mention of any pointer sized integers*" - not in the tutorial, but there is in Go's official documentation for `int`, which I also linked to above.